# ORDER BY RAND() not working within a UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have some problems with ORDER BY RAND() within a UNION. It doesn't seem to order randomly within the seperate queries within a UNION.

I only want to order the sub queries without ordering the whole query at once as the order needs to be Subquery 1 > subquery2 > subquery3.

I've tried some other random functions for MySQL like NEWID() and UUID() but they don't seem to work either.

I'm using WordPress to get the results.

```
SELECT *
        FROM (
                (SELECT act.wordpress_id,
                        act.title,
                        act.main_image,
                        loc.id,
                        "activities" AS type,
                        loc.town,
                        loc.village
                FROM tha_wc_activity act
                INNER JOIN tha_wc_location loc
                ON act.location_id = loc.id
                WHERE
                  act.active = 1 AND
                  act.visible_in_activities_overview = 1 AND
                  loc.id = 1
                ORDER BY RAND()
                )
            UNION
                (SELECT act.wordpress_id,
                        act.title,
                        act.main_image,
                        loc.id,
                        "activities" AS type,
                        loc.town,
                        loc.village
                FROM tha_wc_activity act
                INNER JOIN tha_wc_location loc
                ON act.location_id = loc.id
                WHERE
                  act.active = 1 AND
                  act.visible_in_activities_overview = 1 AND
                  loc.village = "villageName"
                ORDER BY RAND()
                )
            UNION
                (SELECT act.wordpress_id,
                        act.title,
                        act.main_image,
                        loc.id,
                        "activities" AS type,
                        loc.town,
                        loc.village
                FROM tha_wc_activity act
                INNER JOIN tha_wc_location loc
                ON act.location_id = loc.id
                WHERE
                  act.active = 1 AND
                  act.visible_in_activities_overview = 1 AND
                  loc.town = "townName"
                ORDER BY RAND()
                )
            ) AS act
            WHERE act.wordpress_id != 1
            LIMIT 0, 15)
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Gordon Linoff, I found out that I had to put limit on the seperate subqueries else it wouldn't be getting the ordered results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your question is.  You are using `order by rand()` in subqueries, but then selecting all the results.  Getting all the rows is all the rows, regardless of their ordering.

Then, you are using `union` which removes duplicates and have other logic as well.

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select *
from (<subquery 1>
      union
      <subquery 2>
      . . .
     ) t
where . . .
order by rand()
limit 15;
```

There is no need to order the subqueries, unless you use `limit`.

Note that you might want to use `union all` rather than `union` -- unless you explicitly want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: I need to order each subquery separately and put those 3 queries together and return it as 1 query. So order by RAND on the whole query is incorrect because the seperate orders would be ignored and I want the limit on the whole query.